# Recursion using the main function

Tags: c, loops, recursion, static, program-entry-point

I need to find the output of this code. I know that this is recursion but i do not exactly know how this code actually works. I thought that this would be an infinite code but it is not. Can someone please explain me?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 char *str = "kre";
 void main(void) {
     int i;
     static int j = 3;
     for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
         printf("%d ", j--);
         main();
     }
     printf("%sn%c ", str, 'i');
 }
```

Comment: suggestion: single-step through your program with a debugger.

Comment: suggestion 2: use an [indentation style](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) other than "everything left-aligned"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought that this would be an infinite code but it is not

It's not an infinite code because, you declare `static` for `j` (see [What does “static” mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean-in-c)):

```
static int j = 3;
```

The value of `j` will be updated when you call `main` function. You can see the output of your program:

> **3 2 1** kreni kreni kreni kreni

the value of `j` decrement from `3` to `1`, then when `j = 0`, you can not access the `for` loop because the condition `i < j` is not accepted, so the `main()` is not called again.

If you want an infinite code, you remove `static` from declaration of `j`, your program will never be stopped.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, but i still do not understand why it prints "kreni" 4 times when the loop is finished. It is maybe a stupid question but this really confuses me.

Comment: @Petar because, in the last call of `main()`, `j=0`, so you cannot access the `for` loop to print the value of `j` (`printf("%d ", j--);` is called 3 times), but when `j=0` you can still print `kreni`. this is reason why you print `j` 3 times but 4 times for `kreni`

Comment: I thought that output would be "3 kreni 2 kreni 1 kreni" and it confuses me how it prints "3 2 1" in the loop but then prints "kreni" 4 times.

Comment: The function is called when `i=0`, `i=1` and `i=2`. However, don't forget that the first time `main` is called by starting the program.

Comment: @Petar each time you call main, your program back to the first line of main, until `j = 0`, 4 called times of `main` will can reach the line  `printf("%sn%c ", str, 'i');`. You can print the value of `j` in the last `printf`: `printf("%sn%c, j = %d ", str, 'i',j);` to see

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I understand how it works, but I think that when it prints "3 2 1" it still does not reach to the last line, so I think the output should be "3 2 1 kreni" because the code would reach to the last printf only when it can not enter the for loop.

Comment: @Petar `main` is called 4 times (1 in starting program, then 3 in for loop). So `printf("%sn%c ", str, 'i');` is reached in 4 times.

Comment: @Petar Why would it not reach the last line? Which condition would stop the program from continuing after the `main` call or exiting the `for` loop?

Comment: @Cheatah Yes, do attention with `i = 0` in `for` loop. The value of `i` maybe indeterminate before `for` loop, but at starting of `for` loop, `i = 0`